# <MULE> Is there a way to bind file inbound transaction with JMS outbound

Tags: java, mule

Is there a way to bind file inbound transaction with JMS outbound in mule.
Use case is to read file from file inbound and do some processing and write to JMS outbound. however if MQ is down it should rollback complete transaction

Comment: so you expect it to rollback the transaction and retry it again ?

Comment: Yes, if there is any issue rollback current transaction and just retry

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no clear description on what do you mean by "some processing" I am assuming some file data transformation which won't be stored in persistent store and here is how you can attempt the use case

1. have an file connector to read files
2. do processing
3. call JMS outbound with a catch exception strategy. In catch exception strategy handle roll back scenario

Note: If you are processing data needs to be reversed handle that too in exception block.

last but not least, if your processing doesn't have impact on JMS payload (I don't think it is the case - but just a thought) use scatter gather which will make roll back more easy

Comment: In this example "some processing" involves db operation, which are also suppose to be rolled-back in case of exception.

Comment: What about the dependency of "some processing" on JMS message. Are you trying to send a different payload while sending JMS operation that from actual payload in file connector?

Comment: Use scatter gather approach, it will ensure all success or none.